# GameCenter Leaderboards not updating score

Tags: swift, xcode, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I am new to Swift (and coding in general) and have experienced an issue when uploading a score to the GameKit Leaderboard.
I can see all users in the leaderboard, but the score is always "0".
This is the error I am getting in the console:

> ["$s7Combine10PublishersO8SequenceV7receive10subscriberyqd___t7FailureQyd__Rs_AA10SubscriberRd__5InputQyd__7ElementRtzlF +1012", "$s7Combine9PublisherPAAE9subscribeyyqd__AA10SubscriberRd__7FailureQyd__AFRtz5InputQyd__6OutputRtzlF +1060", "_dispatch_call_block_and_release +32", "_dispatch_client_callout +20", "_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF +1000", "CFRunLoopRunSpecific +600", "GSEventRunModal +164", "UIApplicationMain +168", "$s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF +104", "$sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ +120", "$s10PlantATree11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ +48", "main +32"]

How I have been trying to update my scores:

```
func updateScore(with value: Int) {
    let score = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "bp")
    score.value = Int64(value)
    GKScore.report([score]) { (error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("Updated score successfully. ")
        }
    }
}

updateScore(with: score)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I fixed it like this: 

GKLeaderboard.submitScore(self.score, context: 0, player: GKLocalPlayer.local, leaderboardIDs: ["name"]) { error in }